# Indexing from 1 with matplotlib's spy function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

When I plot with the spy function the matrix is plotted with the first index being 0, I would like to have the indices start from 1.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import scipy.sparse as sps
A = sps.rand(10,10, density=0.5)
M = sps.csr_matrix(A)
plt.spy(M)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So you mean you want to change the numbers on the x and y axes?

Comment: Yes I would like the numbers be incremented by 1, eg instead of being 0,1,2 on the x axis I would like it to be 1,2,3

Comment: So why not search the internet or stackoverflow for how to modify matplotlib axis labels?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but I found nothing suitable

Answer (score 0):

All you needed was `plt.xticks()` and `plt.yticks()`. Below is an example for your problem. Here, `range(10)` specifies the location of the labels and `range(1, 11)` specifies the actual labels starting from 0 going up to 10.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import scipy.sparse as sps
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
A = sps.rand(10,10, density=0.5)
M = sps.csr_matrix(A)
plt.spy(M)
plt.xticks(range(10), range(1, 11))
plt.yticks(range(10), range(1, 11))
```

**Output**

[image]